# Why does the MinGW bundled with CLion disables LTO (Link Time Optimization)?

Tags: gcc, mingw, clion, mingw-w64

I found the recent version of CLion come bundled with MinGW. However, it seems that LTO (Link Time Optimization) is disabled (`--disable-lto`). Could anyone tell me why? Thx.

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.1\bin\mingw\bin>gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-11.2.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-alpine-linux-musl --prefix=/win --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-seh-exceptions --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-threads=posix --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-bootstrap --disable-graphite --disable-libada --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-libquadmath --disable-lto --disable-nls --disable-multilib --disable-rpath --disable-symvers --disable-werror --disable-win32-registry --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-system-libiconv --with-system-libz --with-gmp=/win/makedepends --with-mpfr=/win/makedepends --with-mpc=/win/makedepends
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 11.2.0 (GCC)
```

Comment: You will have to ask the person who compiled this gcc release why it was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

We made it pretty minimal to be able to compile simple projects like "Hello, world!" and that's it. It also does not include any tooling like MSYS2, so it's even not possible to install additional development libraries there.